# Java-style variable declaration in the class

Tags: python, coding-style, variable-declaration

I am trying to understand best practices in Python OOP.

I am very familiar with the Java-style workflow of:

1. Attribute Declaration
2. Attribute Instantiation

What I like about it is that it improves readability in my opinion: by having a short look at the attributes, you know exactly with which you will work along the class.

I would like to achieve the same result in Python, while I understand that there is no such thing as "variable declaration" in Python, but maybe some kind of a design pattern that would allow to do just the same.

My intermediate solution so far has been to "declare" inside the `__init__` method, with:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.attribute1 = None
    self.attribute2 = None
```

and instantiate those elements later in subsequent methods.
But I find it rather ugly, and I'd be very happy to hear about a more elegant pattern.

Comment: Setting attributes on the class makes them class attributes, not instance attributes.

Comment: Remember you can accept by clicking the checkmark next to the answer, and it will give you plus 2 to your rep. :)

Answer (score 5):

The best place to declare your inputs is inside your class docstring:

```
class Foo(object):
    '''
    This class of object is instantiated with variables that are attributes:

    attribute1 should be a string
    attribute2 should be a tuple of length two for your parameters:
    '''
    def __init__(attribute1=None, attribute2=None): 
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2
```

And when someone calls `help(Foo)`, the docstring will be printed. This would be instantiated and referenced:

```
help(Foo)
my_foo = Foo('bar', ('baz', 42))
help(my_foo)
```

And note that since we provided defaults of None to the attributes, we can instantiate the object without the attributes given, and check for their instantiation later with `is None`.

Comment: There is a good example of Google-style docstrings [here](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/example_google.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, you can use ["Function Annotations"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) to add metadata on argument and return values:

```
class Demo():

    def __init__(self, attribute1: str, attribute2: "int - number of foos" = 0):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2

    def foo(self) -> int:
        return self.attribute2
```

These aren't enforced (without third-party libraries), but do provide useful information to the users of your classes (e.g. appearing as tooltips in IDEs and in the information provided by `help(Demo)`).